# Differences in solutions of ODE $y''''(x)+a\cdot{}y''(x)+b\cdot{}y(x)=0$

Tags: differential-equations

I have an ODE which form is $y''''(x)+a\cdot{}y''(x)+b\cdot{}y(x)=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are constant values.
I have solved it in two ways.
First one is by using Laplace transform:

```
eq = ( f''''[x] + 2 a*f''[x] + b*f[x]) == 0;
EQ = LaplaceTransform[eq, x, s];
\Phi[s] = Solve[EQ, LaplaceTransform[f[x], x, s]][[1]];
answer1 = InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[f[x], x, s] /. \Phi[s], s, x] /. {f[0] -> C[1], f'[0] -> C[2], f''[0] -> C[3], f'''[0] -> C[4]}
```

Second one is by using build-in command `DSolve`:

```
answer2 = DSolve[{( f''''[x] + 2 a*f''[x] + b*f[x]) == 0}, f[x], x][[1, 1, 2]]
```

As you can noticed I got completely different answers

```
answer1 === answer2
(* False *)
```

This equation describes non-uniform torsion of single bar and proper solution should be `answer1` but I am wondering if there is fastest way (in case of many equations) to solve it by using build-in commands?

Comment: The issue is the lack of boundary conditions in `answer2` and the implicit impulse for the Laplace transform.  You have a fourth-order differential equation and no boundary conditions, so Mma puts in the unknown constants of integration `C[1]` to `C[4]` in answer2.

Comment: Try `rules={E^(Sqrt[-a - Sqrt[a^2 - b]] x) -> pm,  E^(-Sqrt[-a - Sqrt[a^2 - b]] x) -> mm,  E^(Sqrt[-a + Sqrt[a^2 - b]] x) -> pp,  E^(-Sqrt[-a + Sqrt[a^2 - b]] x) -> mp}` and then `Collect[ExpandAll[(answer1 - answer2)] /. rules, {pm, mm, pp, mp}]` to see that each `C` corresponds to a different linear combination of the initial conditions.

Comment: Aside from the issue that the solution space has many bases, `SameQ` (`===`) does not check algebraic equivalence.